# service fabric URL routing

Tags: azure, load-balancing, azure-service-fabric

I am using the Azure Load Balancer with Azure service fabric to host multiple self host web applications, I'd like to create a rule that allows me to route based on the users URL request.

So for example if a user navigates to :

`http:// domain.com/Site1` then the rule would route to:
`http:// domain.com**:8181**/Site1` within the cluster

if the user navigates to:

`http:// domain.com/Site2` then the rule would route to:
`http:// domain.com**:8282**/Site2` within the cluster

Is this possible with azure service fabric/load balancer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Azure Load Balancer only forwards traffic it receives on a port to a node in your cluster on another port (can be the same port or a different internal port). It operates on Layer 4 (TCP, UDP) so it doesn't know anything about HTTP or URLs (although it does allow HTTP probes).

Here are a couple options for multiple web sites:

If you want your web sites hosted internally on different ports (8181 and 8282), then you'll need something else to do URL routing. Azure Traffic Manager or Azure Application Gateway are possible options that would run outside your cluster. Your Azure Load Balancer would need to open a port for each web site, but the benefit is this way you can run your web sites on dedicated nodes and the ALB would automatically route traffic to the appropriate nodes based on which ports are open.

Alternatively, you can set up your own stateless routing service that runs inside your cluster.

Or you can skip routing altogether and just host all of your websites on port 80/443. As long as you're using an http.sys-based web host, which includes Katana, ASP.NET Core 1 WebListener, or anything you build on HttpListener, you can use the same port for all your websites and let the underlying http server route according to either a URL path or hostname, both of which are supported.

Comment: Thanks, in the end I went for the last solution, this seemed the easiest approach and used WebListener in the .barcode app.

Comment: can you please elaborate on option 2?

Comment: `host all of your websites on port 80/443` If you use a method like this with weblistener: https://matt.kotsenas.com/posts/https-in-service-fabric-web-api be weary that when you come to change certificates (e.g. renew) you shall have to take down all services listening on the secured port otherwise you'll run in to issues where the 443 is in use with the old cert, then the new one attempts to use the new cert on 443. Which results in a failure.

Comment: I'm using https://github.com/c3-ls/ServiceFabric-Http/wiki/HTTP-Gateway which is great because it runs inside SF.