# Security for HTTP Service Fabric Routing

Tags: security, azure, network-programming, multi-tenant, azure-service-fabric

With reference to [service fabric URL routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37346019/service-fabric-url-routing).

The accepted answer was to host all the gateways or sites off of port 80/443 (http/https). I ran into this question while researching the security implications of such a design. In my case I have a multi tenant cluster where each tenant is given an application instance (inspiration for this architecture comes from here: [Azure Service Fabric Multi-Tenancy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35247726/azure-service-fabric-multi-tenancy)). Each instance has been registered with their own app root, so essentially their gateway is addressed like this: http:/+{port}/{tenant}. In production I will handle AuthN/Auth on each tenant separately, that isn't my concern.

My question is it secure to share port 80/443 in this fashion? Would each tenant getting a random open port for their tenant not improve the security?